# some blank space remains in QVBoxLayout after hiding widgets (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

There are hundreds of widgets in **QVBoxLayout**. I am hiding/showing them based on option menus. If I hide some of widgets, some blank space remains in QVBoxLayout and I dont want this unnecessary space. Adding spacer at bottom is not solving the issue. Same for setting margin spacing. Its like hidden widgets consume some space. Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layouts have some default spacing between each child widget, defined by `setSpacing()`, `setHorizontalSpacing()`, `setVerticalSpacing()`. Even if you hide the child widget, the spacing around it remains visible. (Note: I think this is a bad design decision made by Qt developers, but we need to live with it.) You have basically these options:

a) Remove the child widget from the layout instead of hiding it. Remember its original position and if it should be shown again, insert it at that position. This is complicated, the original position may be invalidated if you removed some other widgets meanhile, so this would require some clever algorithm for maintaining the correct visual positions of the hidden child widgets in the layout etc. I would not do this, feels too complicated for me.

b) Use zero-sized default spacing in the layout and add spacings manually by https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addSpacing and then when hiding the child widgets, set the size of the `QSpacerItem` next to it to zero. And set it back to non-zero when showing the child widget again.

c) Alternative to a) but do not keep original indexes but have a container of pointers to the child widgets and when a change in the visibility of the child widgets is required, then remove all the items from the layout and put all the child widgets which should be visible to the layout. This means to re-create the content of the layout in each change. Actually this is how I am doing it in my code. I have about 20 widgets and hiding/showing is fast enough. I believe it will be fast enough even for hundreds of widgets.

d) And alternative to c) ... if you have really large number of widgets, then you should consider deleting those which are not supposed to be visible and re-creating them when they are shown. I.e. in c) we keep the widget alive but hidden in a certain container but in d) we delete this widget and create it later again. It depends on your use case whether c) is better than d) or vice versa. My gut feeling is that c) should be fine performance-wise and is simpler.

Note: My reasonging is based on showing and hiding of widgets in grid layout, but I guess that VBox layout has the same principles regarding preserving default spacing even around hidden items.